# Failed propType: The prop `id` is required to make `Dropdown` accessible for users of assistive technologies such as screen readers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is my code for the render of Dropdown menu using react-bootstrap,

```
render(){
    return(
        <SplitButton title={this.state.title}>
          {Object.keys(dict).map(key => <MenuItem id={dict[key]} key={dict[key]} href={`#${dict[key]}`} onSelect={() => this.onTargetSelect(key,dict[key])}>{key}</MenuItem>)}
        </SplitButton>
    );
  }
```

I get the following error,

```
Failed propType: The prop `id` is required to make `Dropdown` accessible for users of assistive technologies such as screen readers. Check the render method of `Uncontrolled(Dropdown)`.
```

I don't have an `id` propType.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that's the point of the message. You're missing `id` on the Dropdown and need to include it.

Comment: That's what I'm failing to understand, where?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's on SplitButton. Seems that that's an implied Dropdown as mentioned [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns).

Answer (score 2):

dropDowns need a valid id, because it is a required prop for the component.

ref: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns-props

Provide an id to the component. It will work fine.

```
<SplitButton bsStyle={title.toLowerCase()} title={title} key={i} id={exampleId}>
      <MenuItem eventKey="1">Action</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem eventKey="2">Another action</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem eventKey="3">Something else here</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem divider />
      <MenuItem eventKey="4">Separated link</MenuItem>
</SplitButton>
```

Comment: Try providing an example of how to give it an id.

Comment: The Ref link is not working,here's the new link https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

`<SplitButton title={this.state.title}>`

to

`<SplitButton title={this.state.title} id="splitButtonMenu">`